# Erro socket.io node.js api changenow

Tags: node.js, api, websocket, socket.io, documentação

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de cambio e preciso receber em tempo real o status das transações e informações de cambio, seguindo a documentação [changenow.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzkYS.png)
porém sempre recebo o seguinte erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

agora o seguinte erro é apresentado [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: mude seu `require` para `var io = require('socket.io');`

Comment: Está dando um erro diferente agora

Comment: Se você não informar qual o erro fica difícil te ajudar